# Invalid XML - Element 'config': Missing child element(s)?

Tags: magento2, checkout, xml, http-error-500

It is in the checkout process. It seems the ajax call get 500. It only appears in the local environment. I don't know how to fix it...

The URL is: **{localhost}/default/rest/default/V1/guest-carts/0b5bcc2be8ad76a0328858ee01fadb17/estimate-shipping-methods**

> Status Code:500

**Response:**

> 1 exception(s): Exception #0
>   (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Invalid XML in file
>   C:/xampp/htdocs/local/vendor/magento/module-checkout/etc/webapi_rest/events.xml:
>   Element 'config': Missing child element(s). Expected is ( event ).
>   Line: 2

Comment: I think the error is pretty self-explanatory.

Comment: Yeah, the error says there is no child element in the xml file, but I look at the same file in another host who can send the ajax call successfully, the xml file is the same...

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the Unit Test: `vendor/magento/framework/Event/Test/Unit/Config/_files/invalidEventsXmlArray.php`

```
'without_event_handle' => [
        '<?xml version="1.0"?><config></config>',
        ["Element 'config': Missing child element(s). Expected is ( event ).\nLine: 1\n"],
    ],
```

So, may need to check our **events xml config** in our custom module again.

Comment: Fixed. It is the xml problem. should add the xml event handler child node. Thanks !

Comment: @Jessie if my answer is helpful, please accept it.

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh I am getting this error : Element 'route': Missing child element(s). Expected is ( resources ).